# Assigning array elements based on elements in another array

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

First time post here, and I had a (likely very simple) question.

I wanted to assign the values of elements in one array (A) based on the corresponding values in another array(B), eg if A(1)=2 assign 4 to B(1).

I imagined this would be achieved using DO loops and some if statements. However the If staments I'm using seem to refering to the loop index rather than the specific element at that point.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Can you provide some code and an example of what it's supposed to do?

Comment: There is nothing bad with loops. I am always surprised to see people inventing very clever array expressions, just to avoid loops which are probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use *masked array assignment*.  Given two arrays, `A` and `B`, of the same shape (ie same number of ranks, same size in each dimension), and if you wanted to set elements of `B` to 4 where the corresponding element of `A` equals `2` you could simply write

```
where(A==2) B = 4
```

`where` teams up with `elsewhere`, rather like `if` and `else if`, and there is an `end where` too.  Consult your favourite documentation for further details.

If you can't express your operation with `where` you might (if you have an up to date compiler) be interested in the `do concurrent` construct.  And, if all else fails, there are good old-fashioned `do` and `if` to fall back on.

Comment: I ought to add, in recognition of the point Francois Jacq makes above, that too much of modern Fortran programming time is indeed spent devising very clever array expressions, comparing them with equivalent loop-based code (which would have taken about 1/10th the time to devise), and then learning that the loop-based approach is faster.  `where` is neat, but don't be surprised if `do` gets to the prize.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try a construct with [`merge`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MERGE.html)... `merge` constructs a new array from two existing arrays using a mask to choose the correct value:

```
program test
  integer,parameter :: LENGTH=5
  integer :: A(LENGTH)
  integer :: B(LENGTH)
  real    :: R(LENGTH)
  integer :: i

  call random_number(R)
  A = int( R*3 )
  B = [ ( i,i=1,LENGTH) ]

  print *,'A:',A

  print *,'B:',B
  B = merge( 4, B, A == 2 )
  print *,'B:',B
end program
```

Output:

```
 A:           2           1           2           2           1
 B:           1           2           3           4           5
 B:           4           2           4           4           5
```

Explanation:

```
  B = merge( 4, B, A == 2 )
```

- `A == 2` constructs a temporary logical array which is `.true.` at `i` if `A(i) == 2`
- `4` in this case is a temporary array with the same length as `B`
- So, `merge` choses the value from `4` if the temporary logical array is `.true.`, and the correspond value from `B`, otherwise.
- The resulting vector is written back to `B` (`=`)